# How to install mod_wsgi 4.4.13 with python 3.4 on CentOS6.X

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

How do i install mod_wsgi 4.4.13 with python3.4 ?

Followings are installed  binutils, gcc, httpd , python3.4

```
python installed alias created 
python='/usr/bin/python3'
       /usr/bin/python3
```

wsgi Package downloaded & extracted :mod_wsgi-4.4.13

Got an error while installing.

Error :

```
mod_wsgi-4.4.13]# ls
config.log     configure.ac  images    Makefile.in        PKG-INFO    setup.py  win32
config.status  CREDITS.rst   LICENSE   MANIFEST.in        README.rst  src
configure      docs          Makefile  mod_wsgi.egg-info  setup.cfg   tests

# ./configure --enable-shared --profix=/usr/bin/python configure: error: unrecognized option: `--profix=/usr/bin/python' Try `./configure --help' for more information
# which python alias
python='/usr/bin/python3'
        /usr/bin/python3
# which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

If i asked anything in wrong manner please guide me .I love to learn .

Thanks
Sandra

Comment: `--profix` seems like a typo, should probably be `--prefix`. You should check `./configure --help` for all the options available.

Comment: I installed now " yum install httpd-devel " 

while make got and error as

Comment: Thank you Baris demiray .

next step error while make . please find the pastebin

http://pastebin.com/JfX0yh80

Comment: You need to install `python-devel` package. Also, why do you want to install `mod_wsgi-4.4.13` into `/usr/bin/python3`? That seems very wrong and has a great potential for clashes when you install Python.

Comment: The '--prefix' option to 'configure' for mod_wsgi is from memory ignored. When the compiled module is installed it is installed based on where Apache (via 'apxs' command) says the Apache modules should reside.

Comment: Kindly share step by step walk through  would be  make myself very understandable .

Comment: Installed perfectly and works great .Thank you all